# Duplication of actions in react-redux app

Tags: redux, react-redux

[image: Pomodoro-redux]

Incrementing any of the timers, increments both. What could be the problem? I tried changing the names of action.type even action creators, it still didn't work.

GitHub URL: https://github.com/algomaster99/pomodoro-redux

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are using/dispatching the same actions in your reducers/containers. You can follow this steps to solve your issue:

1. Write a different action `~/Actions/sessionLength.js` to handle session length.
2. In `sessionReducer.js`, use the actions you added in step 1.
3. In `sessionLengthContainer.js`, dispatch the actions you added in step 1.

Note that you will also need to make sure your action types are unique. For example, use `INCREMENT_BREAK_LENGTH` rather than `INCREMENT`.